# Can I create a function to break a while loops in python?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am writing a program with python to simulate flipping a coin or rolling dice.  The coin and dice use while loops to give the user the option to roll or flip again, an example is:

```
def d4():
    d4ing = True
    while d4ing:        
        print(random.randint(1,4))
        done = input("""would you like to roll again?  Type y to roll again,
type d to roll a dice, or type anything else to exit:""")
        if done == "y":
            continue
        elif done == "d":
            break
        else:
            print("thank you for using my coin/dice simulator")
            sys.exit("goodbye")
```

The problem I am having is that I would like to take every line starting from done and make it into it's own function that I can just insert into every function rather than typing the whole thing out again and again, like this.

```
def d4ing():
    d4ing = True
    while d4ing:
        print(random.randint(1,4))
        rerolling()

def rerolling(): 
    done = input("""would you like to roll again? Type y to roll again, type d to roll a dice, or type anything else to exit:""") 
    if done == "y": 
        continue 
    elif done == "d": 
        break else: 
    print("thank you for using my coin/dice simulator")     
    sys.exit("goodbye")
```

The error message I am getting:

```
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

Comment: So, what prevents you from doing what you would like? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: I tried to create a function called rerolling() and it comes up with a syntax error that continue and break are not properly in a loop.  Thank you for help editing the question, I'm new to the site.

Comment: Please show us what you did and _specifically_ include the complete error message.

Comment: You cannot break if you are not inside the loop.

Comment: def rerolling():
        done = input("""would you like to roll again?  Type y to roll again,
    type d to roll a dice, or type anything else to exit:""")
        if done == "y":
            continue
        elif done == "d":
            break
        else:
            print("thank you for using my coin/dice simulator")
            sys.exit("goodbye")

The error message I am getting is:
    continue
    ^
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: Please [edit] your code into the question. As you've found out, it's unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

A `break` or a `continue` must be in a loop in its current scope. You cannot break a loop in the above scope from inside a function. Here is a general example of what raises the `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` error. The same holds for `continue`.

```
def break_up():
    break # This is a syntax error

while True:
    break_up()
```

Although, this is not a problem, since you can make the function return a value and conditionally `break` in the upper scope.

In your specific example though, you can also return whether or not you want to reroll by assigning the return value to `d4ing`.

```
def d4():
    d4ing = True
    while d4ing:        
        print(random.randint(1,4))
        d4ing = rerolling()

def rerolling():
    done = input("Would you like to roll again?")
    if done == "y":
        return True
    elif done == "d":
        return False
    else:
        print("thank you for using my coin/dice simulator")
        sys.exit("goodbye")
```